# SQL Server Join Query DateCompleted > 3 Years Ago

Tags: sql-server, join

I have the below 2 tables in an SQL Server database.

Asset Table -

```
Id,
AssetName
```

Inspections Table -

```
Id,
AssetId, (<- This is Id in the Assets table)
InspectionName,
DateStarted,
DateDue,
DateCompleted
```

An asset can have multiple inspections listed in the Inspections table. How can I create a query where an assets newest inspection is greater than 3 years old? (DateCompleted > 3 years ago for the newest inspection).

The query I currently have:

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.AssetName FROM [Assets] AS t1 INNER JOIN [Inspections] AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.AssetID WHERE [DateCompleted] < DATEADD(year, -3, GETDATE()) AND t1.Id NOT IN (SELECT t1.Id FROM [Assets] AS t1 INNER JOIN [Inspections] AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.AssetID WHERE [DateCompleted] BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())
```

Thanks
Paul.

Comment: Show the query you have now

Comment: SELECT t1.Id, t1.AssetName FROM [Assets] AS t1 INNER JOIN [Inspections] AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.AssetID WHERE [DateCompleted] < DATEADD(year, -3, GETDATE()) AND t1.Id NOT IN (SELECT t1.Id FROM [Assets] AS t1 INNER JOIN [Inspections] AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.AssetID WHERE [DateCompleted] BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    T1.Id,
    T1.AssetName,
    MAX(DateCompleted) AS InspectionDate
FROM Asset T1
LEFT JOIN Inspections T2 ON T1.Id = T2.AssetId
GROUP BY T1.Id, T1.AssetName
HAVING MAX(DateCompleted) < DATEADD(YY, -3, GETDATE()) -- OR MAX(DateExam) IS NULL (if you want to include assets that were not inspectioned at all)
```

Comment: why the `LEFT JOIN` ?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is to include Assets that don't have related Inspections for the `OR MAX(DateExam) IS NULL` part to work

Answer (score 0):

this should gives you what you wanted. You group by Id & AssetName and find the Max `DateCompleted` and compare with date that you required

```
SELECT  t1.Id, t1.AssetName 
FROM    [Assets] AS t1 
        INNER JOIN [Inspections] AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.AssetID 
GROUP BY t1.Id, t1.AssetName 
HAVING  MAX (t2.[DateCompleted] )   < DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE())
```